# size of horizontal line in \moderncvtheme[...]{classic} theme

Tags: moderncv

is it possible to make the the horizontal line in the section headings less thick in the classic theme, without changing the font size of the heading? Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this to your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\newlength{\hintscolumnthickness}
\setlength{\hintscolumnthickness}{3pt}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{\hintscolumnthickness}}}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}
\makeatother
```

now by changing the third line with the desired thickness you get what you asked.